# Reducing the number of heap allocations when enqueuing tasks

Tags: multithreading, c++11, boost-thread, stdthread

Heap allocations are a bottleneck in my application and I would like to avoid them when sending small tasks to my thread pool.

Can I use a `std::packaged_task` with a stack allocator? Under which conditions? What are the pros/cons of this choice? Are there better alternatives to avoid heap allocations of `std::future`'s shared state by operator `new` ?

```
auto foo() {
  arena<1024> buffer;
  auto task = std::packaged_task<int()>{
    std::allocator_arg_t, 
    arena_allocator{arena},
    []() -> int { return 5; } 
  };
  auto f = task.get_future();  // is this future and its shared state stack allocated?
  thread_pool.push_back(std::move(task)); 
  // I will probably need to block before the stack goes out of scope..
  return f.get();
}
```

Comment: If you are going to block waiting for another thread to complete the task, you might as well just run the task on this thread directly. That seems to defeat the whole point of having multiple threads.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm going to ensure that the computation finishes before returning, that doesn't mean that I'm going to wait. This enables me to do something else on this thread while some computation runs on another thread, or to run multiple computations on multiple threads. It also allows me to pass the future down the stack as it grows... Or to even execute the computation on a detached thread as long as I ensure that it terminates before the local stack where the shared state lives is invalidated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "I will probably need to block before the stack goes out of scope" comment clearly identifies the only issue here. The only thing you must make sure is that because the task in your sending thread's stack, it has to stay there until your thread pool executes it.

Other than that, there are no issues with using the stack, instead of heap allocation.